# I am trying to make an interface from where we can with on button click execute .exe files to install a s/w

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, exe

This is my main class, wherein run(), I am calling one another method install setup() which is for exe files.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
   }  
public void startSetup() {
Runnable task=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                installSetup();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }; 

Thread thread=new  Thread(task);
thread.start();
}
```

Here is my installsetup() method

```
  public void installSetup() {
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:path\\setup.exe", null, new File("C:pathfolder\\01_Setupexe"));
        //process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
};
```

I am calling it in my controller class like this:

```
public class Controller extends Thread {
  @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> dsetup;
  public void generateRandom() {
     if(dsetup.getValue()!=null) dsetupValue = dsetup.getValue().toString();
     if(dsetupValue!=null)call.startSetup();
```

Before I was just calling the install files with the exec method but not with threads concept, the application was working fine, but it was executing all the.exe files at once and then my interface freezes. So now I am using threads concept and trying to implement one thread at a time. I don't understand if it is a wrong way or not, but I do not get any error in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runtime.exec has been obsolete for many years.  Use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\path\\setup.exe");
builder.directory(new File("C:pathfolder\\01_Setupexe"));
builder.inheritIO();
builder.start();
```

The inheritIO() method will make the spawned process use the Java program’s stdin, stdout, and stderr, so it will not hang waiting for input or waiting for an available output buffer.

I doubt you need the new Thread or the sleep call, but I don’t know what files you’re calling or whether they depend on each other.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I made 5 different threads for all the setup files. I need to run setup in serial order one setup is a requirement of the second one.

Comment: Use [Process.waitFor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) to know when each process has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly exec has some pitfalls. Most of the time using the process aproche (see Listing 4.3) saved me related to buffer issues and so on.
https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

> ```
> import java.util.*;
> import java.io.*;
> public class MediocreExecJavac
> {
>     public static void main(String args[])
>     {
>         try
>         {            
>             Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
>             Process proc = rt.exec("javac");
>             InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
>             InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
>             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
>             String line = null;
>             System.out.println("<ERROR>");
>             while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
>                 System.out.println(line);
>             System.out.println("</ERROR>");
>             int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
>             System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
>         } catch (Throwable t)
>           {
>             t.printStackTrace();
>           }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Source: javaworld

Comment: *this examples has some stuff in it which can be removed since you don't need the outputs*  Ignoring the output(s) from the child process will cause problems for any child process that actually writes enough data to fill up its standard output or standard error pipe buffers.  With nowhere for that data to go, the child process is likely to block indefinitely.

Comment: Yes, I just mean the additional println calls like  `System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);` thats all. I will remove this line since it don't provide any helpful info.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will try it.